# Create a C# component for a SplashScreen

Tags: c#, user-controls, splash-screen

I want create a new component which shows a splash screen when i call the .show() method. The component must be like a Windows Form with an image and a duration in msec passed like parameters. What type of project should I choose in Visual Studio for do that? If I choose a ClassLibrary, it create a dll Class but if I choose a new ControlLibrary it create a new control, but I can't use a Windows Form.

```
    protected int nSec;

    public SplashScreen(string img, int nSec)
    {
        // duration
        this.nSec = nSec;

        // background splash screen
        this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("img.jpg");

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SplashScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = nSec * 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close()
    }
```

I want reuse this "component" in other future work without create a new one every time.

Comment: You need something to be like a Windows Form but you can't use Windows Forms. Do you mean you can't use a Windows Form project template? Or you can't use a Form object?

Comment: Sounds like they want you to make a class library and have it create the form, you can then just obviously call reference that library and call the desired function when you want the splash screen.

Comment: But I should create a ClassLibrary that contains a Windows Form with my Splash Screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like they want you to make a class library and have it create the form for you.

```
//Whatever other usings you want
using System.Windows.Forms;  //Include the win forms namespace so you create the form

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
public static class Class1
{

    public static Form CreateNewForm()
    {

        var form1 = new Form();
        form1.Width = 200;
        form1.Height = 200;
        form1.Visible = true;
        form1.Activate();        //Unsure if you need to call Activate...
        //You're going to want to modify all the values you want the splash screen to have here
        return form1;

    }   

}
```

}

So in another project, say a console app, I can just reference the class library I just made, call the CreateForm function and it's gonna make a form at runtime pop up with a width and height of 200.

```
using ClassLibrary1; //You'll need to reference this

    //Standard console app template

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = Class1.CreateNewForm(); //Bam form pops up, now just make it a splash screen.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Hope that's what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

Avoid assuming there's magic behind these project templates, you can easily configure the project yourself.  Using the Class Library project template is fine, just right-click the project after you created it, pick Add New Item and select "Windows Form".  Other than adding the form and opening it in the designer, that also added two items to your project's References node: System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms

Which you automatically get when you pick the "Windows Forms Control Library" project template.  Which also automatically added a UserControl.  Which you don't need, just right-click the UserControl1.cs item in the project and pick Delete.  Add New Item to select "Windows Form", just as above.  Two ways to get the same result.